# Pandas How to create a column based on previous chronological values?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I'm having a bit of trouble with pandas. Here is a dataframe that I have:

```
index        val1   cond1     calc1      
2022-05-12    10    False      nan       
2022-05-13    14    True       32        
2022-05-14    20    False      32       
2022-05-15    25    False      32       
2022-05-16    12    False      32       
2022-05-17    11    True       40        
2022-05-18    32    False      40       
2022-05-19    35    False      40       
2022-05-20    40    False      40       
2022-05-21    30    False      40       
2022-05-22    28    True       31        
2022-05-23    15    False      31       
2022-05-24    18    False      31       
2022-05-25    31    False      31
```

I would like to set a new column with True values as soon as val1 equals calc1 when cond1 was set to True, like this: (This is the result I want)

```
index        val1   cond1     calc1      cond2
2022-05-12    10    False      nan       False
2022-05-13    14    True       32        False
2022-05-14    20    False      32        False
2022-05-15    25    False      32        False
2022-05-16    12    False      32        False
2022-05-17    11    True       40        False
2022-05-18    32    False      40        True
2022-05-19    35    False      40        False
2022-05-20    40    False      40        False
2022-05-21    30    False      40        False
2022-05-22    28    True       31        False
2022-05-23    15    False      31        False
2022-05-24    18    False      31        False
2022-05-25    31    False      31        True
```

Sadly using df.apply gives me this result (line with val1 32 is not set to true as there's a 'new' 40 chronologically): (This is the result I get, but I don't want)

```
df['cond2'] = df.apply(lambda x: True if x['val1'] == x['calc1'] else False, axis=1)

index        val1   cond1     calc1      cond2
2022-05-12    10    False      nan       False
2022-05-13    14    True       32        False
2022-05-14    20    False      32        False
2022-05-15    25    False      32        False
2022-05-16    12    False      32        False
2022-05-17    11    True       40        False
2022-05-18    32    False      40        False
2022-05-19    35    False      40        False
2022-05-20    40    False      40        True
2022-05-21    30    False      40        False
2022-05-22    28    True       31        False
2022-05-23    15    False      31        False
2022-05-24    18    False      31        False
2022-05-25    31    False      31        True
```

Eventually I would like to calculate the difference between val1 when cond2 is True and val1 when cond1 is True (here 18 = 32-14) on the same row as cond2 is True: (This is the final result I want)

```
index        val1   cond1     calc1      cond2    diff
2022-05-12    10    False      nan       False    nan
2022-05-13    14    True       32        False    nan
2022-05-14    20    False      32        False    nan
2022-05-15    25    False      32        False    nan
2022-05-16    12    False      32        False    nan
2022-05-17    11    True       40        False    nan
2022-05-18    32    False      40        True     18
2022-05-19    35    False      40        False    nan
2022-05-20    40    False      40        False    nan
2022-05-21    30    False      40        False    nan
2022-05-22    28    True       31        False    nan
2022-05-23    15    False      31        False    nan
2022-05-24    18    False      31        False    nan
2022-05-25    31    False      31        True     3
```

Yes a loop works but it takes a considerable amount of time for the data, I need a faster solution.

Any help would gladly be appreciated, I'm getting really lost here.

Comment: `2022-05-18`'s `con2` is True or False? Based on your condition, it should be False(32 ≠  40).

Comment: @BaronLegendre
I need cond2 to be True on row 2022-05-18 because val1 = 32, which is the value of calc1 when cond1 was True (on 2022-05-13). The condition I've written is what I've tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: `2022-05-20`'s `cond2` should be `True`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproduce

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'index':pd.date_range(start='2022-05-12', periods=14),
   'val1':[10,14,20,25,12,11,32,35,40,30,28,15,18,31],
    'cond1':[False,True,False,False,False,True,False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False],
    'calc1':[np.nan,32,32,32,32,40,40,40,40,40,31,31,31,31]
})
df
###
        index  val1  cond1  calc1
0  2022-05-12    10  False    NaN
1  2022-05-13    14   True   32.0
2  2022-05-14    20  False   32.0
3  2022-05-15    25  False   32.0
4  2022-05-16    12  False   32.0
5  2022-05-17    11   True   40.0
6  2022-05-18    32  False   40.0
7  2022-05-19    35  False   40.0
8  2022-05-20    40  False   40.0
9  2022-05-21    30  False   40.0
10 2022-05-22    28   True   31.0
11 2022-05-23    15  False   31.0
12 2022-05-24    18  False   31.0
13 2022-05-25    31  False   31.0
```

#### cross-validate by matrix manipulation

```
v = df['val1'].values[:, None]
print(v)
###
[[10]
 [14]
 [20]
 [25]
 [12]
 [11]
 [32]
 [35]
 [40]
 [30]
 [28]
 [15]
 [18]
 [31]]
```

```
t = df['calc1'].values
print(t)
###
[nan 32. 32. 32. 32. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 31. 31. 31. 31.]
```

```
m = v == t
###
m
```

[image]

```
continuous_hold = np.arange(len(df)) - np.argmax(m, axis=1)
print(continuous_hold)
###
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  5  7  3  9 10 11 12  3]
```

```
sample_slot = np.split(continuous_hold, np.where(np.diff(continuous_hold) != 1)[0]+1)
sample_slot
###
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 array([5]),
 array([7]),
 array([3]),
 array([ 9, 10, 11, 12]),
 array([3])]
```

```
selection = pd.DataFrame(sample_slot)[1][pd.DataFrame(sample_slot)[1].notna()].values
print(selection)
###
[ 1. 10.]
```

```
df2 = df.iloc[selection,:].drop(columns=['index','cond1']).astype('int64')
df2.columns = {'cond2','target_val'}
df2 = df2.iloc[:, ::-1]
print(df2)
###
    target_val  cond2
1           32     14
10          31     28
```

#### Merge them based on the criteria, and generate results.

```
df3 = df.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='val1', right_on='target_val')
df3['diff'] = df3['val1'] - df3['con2']
df3.drop(columns=['target_val'], inplace=True)
df3
###
        index  val1  cond1  calc1  cond2  diff
0  2022-05-12    10  False    NaN    NaN   NaN
1  2022-05-13    14   True   32.0    NaN   NaN
2  2022-05-14    20  False   32.0    NaN   NaN
3  2022-05-15    25  False   32.0    NaN   NaN
4  2022-05-16    12  False   32.0    NaN   NaN
5  2022-05-17    11   True   40.0    NaN   NaN
6  2022-05-18    32  False   40.0   14.0  18.0
7  2022-05-19    35  False   40.0    NaN   NaN
8  2022-05-20    40  False   40.0    NaN   NaN
9  2022-05-21    30  False   40.0    NaN   NaN
10 2022-05-22    28   True   31.0    NaN   NaN
11 2022-05-23    15  False   31.0    NaN   NaN
12 2022-05-24    18  False   31.0    NaN   NaN
13 2022-05-25    31  False   31.0   28.0   3.0
```

Once `merge()` has done the job and output `diff`, `cond2` could be dropped, but I'll leave the format like yours.

```
df3['cond2'] = df3['cond2'].notna()
df3
###
        index  val1  cond1  calc1  cond2  diff
0  2022-05-12    10  False    NaN  False   NaN
1  2022-05-13    14   True   32.0  False   NaN
2  2022-05-14    20  False   32.0  False   NaN
3  2022-05-15    25  False   32.0  False   NaN
4  2022-05-16    12  False   32.0  False   NaN
5  2022-05-17    11   True   40.0  False   NaN
6  2022-05-18    32  False   40.0   True  18.0
7  2022-05-19    35  False   40.0  False   NaN
8  2022-05-20    40  False   40.0  False   NaN
9  2022-05-21    30  False   40.0  False   NaN
10 2022-05-22    28   True   31.0  False   NaN
11 2022-05-23    15  False   31.0  False   NaN
12 2022-05-24    18  False   31.0  False   NaN
13 2022-05-25    31  False   31.0   True   3.0
```

Reference:
[[01]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56088857/how-to-vectorize-pandas-dataframe-forward-column-value-search)(How to vectorize pandas dataframe forward column value search)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your fast reply. Secondly, sorry next time I'll create the dataframe so you won't have to do it.
To answer your previous question, actually no on the 2022-05-20 cond2 must be False because between 2022-05-18 and 2022-05-20 cond1 wasn't True.
Chronologically:
2022-05-13: cond1 is True so we 'memorize' calc1
2022-05-18: val1 = calc1 on 2022-05-13 -> we set cond2 to True and calculate diff
2022-05-22: cond1 is True so we 'memorize' calc1
2022-05-25: val1 = calc1 on 2022-05-22 -> we set cond2 to True and calculate diff

Hope it's clearer :)

Comment: Also I should add: Only the first True for cond1 must be taken in account, until val1 = calc1 when the first cond1 = True. Once we have cond1 is True, we 'wait' until val1 = calc1 from cond1 is True, the rest must be omitted. I really have a chronological problem :)

Comment: Yeah, I see the meticulous part, then it'll solve by algebra solution.

Comment: I didn't think about using a matrix, that's brilliant!
I'll apply it to my model and I'll come back to properly thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your time and your solution, which works but sadly can't apply to my actual model. I'm afraid I've simplified it way too much. Still, thank you for your teachings.
I've created another post with a more complicated dataframe that looks more like my model, if you want to have a look: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73046621/moving-forward-in-a-panda-dataframe-looking-for-the-first-occurrence-of-multi-co