# Moving forward in a panda dataframe looking for the first occurrence of multi-conditions with reset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, forward

I am having trouble with multi-conditions moving forward in a dataframe.

Here's a simplification of my model:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':pd.date_range(start='2022-05-12', periods=27),
    'l': [10.0,9.9,11.1,10.9,12.1,9.6,13.1,17.9,18.0,15.6,13.5,14.2,10.5,9.5,7.6,9.8,10.2,15.3,17.7,21.8,10.9,18.9,16.4,13.3,7.1,6.8,9.4],
    'c': [10.5,10.2,12.0,11.7,13.5,10.9,13.9,18.2,18.8,16.2,15.1,14.8,11.8,10.1,8.9,10.5,11.1,16.9,19.8,22.0,15.5,20.1,17.7,14.8,8.9,7.3,10.1],
    'h': [10.8,11.5,13.4,13.6,14.2,11.4,15.8,18.5,19.2,16.9,16.0,15.3,12.9,10.5,9.2,11.1,12.3,18.5,20.1,23.5,21.1,20.5,18.2,15.4,9.6,8.4,10.5],
    'oc': [False,True,False,False,False,True,True,True,False,False,True,False,True,False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False],
    's': [np.nan,9.3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,14.5,14.4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,8.1,np.nan,10.7,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,6.9,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
    'i': [np.nan,9.0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,13.6,13.4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,7.0,np.nan,9.9,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,9.2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
    't': [np.nan,15.5,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,16.1,15.9,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,16.5,np.nan,17.2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,25.0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
})

df = df.set_index('date')
# df Index is datetime type

print(df)

               l     c     h     oc     s     i     t
date                                                 
2022-05-12  10.0  10.5  10.8  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-13   9.9  10.2  11.5   True   9.3   9.0  15.5
2022-05-14  11.1  12.0  13.4  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-15  10.9  11.7  13.6  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-16  12.1  13.5  14.2  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-17   9.6  10.9  11.4   True  14.5  13.6  16.1
2022-05-18  13.1  13.9  15.8   True  14.4  13.4  15.9
2022-05-19  17.9  18.2  18.5   True   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-20  18.0  18.8  19.2  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-21  15.6  16.2  16.9  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-22  13.5  15.1  16.0   True   8.1   7.0  16.5
2022-05-23  14.2  14.8  15.3  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-24  10.5  11.8  12.9   True  10.7   9.9  17.2
2022-05-25   9.5  10.1  10.5  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-26   7.6   8.9   9.2  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-27   9.8  10.5  11.1  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-28  10.2  11.1  12.3  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-29  15.3  16.9  18.5   True   6.9   9.2  25.0
2022-05-30  17.7  19.8  20.1  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-05-31  21.8  22.0  23.5  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-06-01  10.9  15.5  21.1  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-06-02  18.9  20.1  20.5  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-06-03  16.4  17.7  18.2  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-06-04  13.3  14.8  15.4  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-06-05   7.1   8.9   9.6  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-06-06   6.8   7.3   8.4  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
2022-06-07   9.4  10.1  10.5  False   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

This is the result I am trying to achieve:

```
         date     l     c     h     oc     s     i     t    cc  diff    r
0  2022-05-12  10.0  10.5  10.8  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
1  2022-05-13   9.9  10.2  11.5   True   9.3   9.0  15.5   NaN   NaN  NaN
2  2022-05-14  11.1  12.0  13.4  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
3  2022-05-15  10.9  11.7  13.6  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
4  2022-05-16  12.1  13.5  14.2  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
5  2022-05-17   9.6  10.9  11.4   True  14.5  13.6  16.1   NaN   NaN  NaN
6  2022-05-18  13.1  13.9  15.8   True  14.4  13.4  15.9  True   5.3    t
7  2022-05-19  17.9  18.2  18.5   True   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
8  2022-05-20  18.0  18.8  19.2  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
9  2022-05-21  15.6  16.2  16.9  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
10 2022-05-22  13.5  15.1  16.0   True   8.1   7.0  16.5   NaN   NaN  NaN
11 2022-05-23  14.2  14.8  15.3  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
12 2022-05-24  10.5  11.8  12.9   True  10.7   9.9  17.2   NaN   NaN  NaN
13 2022-05-25   9.5  10.1  10.5  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
14 2022-05-26   7.6   8.9   9.2  False   NaN   NaN   NaN  True  -7.0    s
15 2022-05-27   9.8  10.5  11.1  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
16 2022-05-28  10.2  11.1  12.3  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
17 2022-05-29  15.3  16.9  18.5   True   6.9   9.2  25.0   NaN   NaN  NaN
18 2022-05-30  17.7  19.8  20.1  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
19 2022-05-31  21.8  22.0  23.5  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
20 2022-06-01  10.9  15.5  21.1  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
21 2022-06-02  18.9  20.1  20.5  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
22 2022-06-03  16.4  17.7  18.2  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
23 2022-06-04  13.3  14.8  15.4  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
24 2022-06-05   7.1   8.9   9.6  False   NaN   NaN   NaN  True  -7.7    i
25 2022-06-06   6.8   7.3   8.4  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
26 2022-06-07   9.4  10.1  10.5  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Principles:

- We always move forward in the dataframe
- When oc is True we 'memorize' both c, s, i and t values from this row
- Moving forward we look for the first occurrence of one of the following conditions:

1. h >= t
2. l <= s
3. l <= i

When it happens we set cc to True and we calculate the difference of the 'memorized' values when oc was True and write a letter to distinguish the condition:

- If h >= t: diff = t-c and r = 't'
- If l <= s: diff = s-c and r = 's'
- If l <= i: diff = i-c and r = 'i'

Once one of the conditions has been met, we look again for oc is True and then the conditions to be met, until the end of the dataframe.

If oc is True again before one of the conditions has been met, we omit it.

What happens chronologically:

1. 2022-05-13: oc is True so we memorize c, s, i, t
2. 2022-05-17: oc is True but none of the conditions have been met, yet -> omission
3. 2022-05-18: h > t[2022-05-13] -> diff = t[2022-05-13]-c[2022-05-13] = 15.5-10.2 = 5.3, r = 't'
4. 2022-05-22: oc is True so we memorize c, s, i, t
5. 2022-05-24: oc is True but none of the conditions have been met, yet -> omission
6. 2022-05-26: l < s[2022-05-22] -> diff = s[2022-05-22]-c[2022-05-22] = 8.1-15.1 = -7.0, r = 's'
7. 2022-05-29: oc is True so we memorize c, s, i, t
8. 2022-06-05: l < i[2022-05-29] -> diff = i[2022-05-29]-c[2022-05-29] = 9.2-16.9 = -7.7, r = 'i'

A loop works but take an enormous amount of time, if possible I'd like to avoid it.

I've tried a really good solution from [Baron Legendre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14527886/baron-legendre) described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73016591/pandas-how-to-create-a-column-based-on-previous-chronological-values) which works perfectly when looking for equal values but I can't seem to adapt it to my model. Also I'm having an index problem: I'm getting different results when using a datetime Index even when I reset it.

I've been stuck with that problem for a while now so any help would gladly be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *oc is True but none of the conditions have been met, yet -> omission*? There are 2 conditions (s and i) for 2022-05-17.

Comment: @Corralien
Absolutely right, sorry about that. I've made the correction. Thank you for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use the commented code below:

```
mem = False  # Memory flag
data = []  # Store new values

# Create groups to speed the process (remove rows before first valid oc)
grp = df['oc'].cumsum().loc[lambda x: x > 0]

# For each group
for _, subdf in df.groupby(grp):
    # Memorize new oc fields (c, s, i, t)
    if not mem:
        oc = subdf.iloc[0][['c', 's', 'i', 't']]
        mem = True
    # Extract l and h fields
    lh = subdf.iloc[1:][['l', 'h']]
    
    # Try to extract the first row where one of conditions is met
    sr = (pd.concat([lh['h'] >= oc['t'], lh['l'] <= oc['s'], lh['l'] <= oc['i']],
                    keys=['t', 's', 'i'], axis=1)
            .rename_axis(columns='r').stack().rename('cc')
            .loc[lambda x: x].head(1).reset_index('r').squeeze())

    # Keep this row if exists and unlock memory
    if not sr.empty:
        sr['diff'] = oc[sr['r']] - oc['c']
        data.append(sr)
        mem = False

# Merge new values 
out = df.join(pd.concat(data, axis=1).T[['cc', 'r', 'diff']])
```

Output:

```
>>> out
               l     c     h     oc     s     i     t    cc    r diff
date                                                                 
2022-05-12  10.0  10.5  10.8  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-13   9.9  10.2  11.5   True   9.3   9.0  15.5   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-14  11.1  12.0  13.4  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-15  10.9  11.7  13.6  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-16  12.1  13.5  14.2  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-17   9.6  10.9  11.4   True  14.5  13.6  16.1   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-18  13.1  13.9  15.8  False   NaN   NaN   NaN  True    t  5.3
2022-05-19  17.9  18.2  18.5  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-20  18.0  18.8  19.2  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-21  15.6  16.2  16.9  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-22  13.5  15.1  16.0   True   8.1   7.0  16.5   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-23  14.2  14.8  15.3  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-24  10.5  11.8  12.9   True  10.7   9.9  17.2   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-25   9.5  10.1  10.5  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-26   7.6   8.9   9.2  False   NaN   NaN   NaN  True    s -7.0
2022-05-27   9.8  10.5  11.1  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-28  10.2  11.1  12.3  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-29  15.3  16.9  18.5   True   6.9   9.2  25.0   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-30  17.7  19.8  20.1  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-05-31  21.8  22.0  23.5  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-06-01  10.9  15.5  21.1  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-06-02  18.9  20.1  20.5  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-06-03  16.4  17.7  18.2  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-06-04  13.3  14.8  15.4  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-06-05   7.1   8.9   9.6  False   NaN   NaN   NaN  True    i -7.7
2022-06-06   6.8   7.3   8.4  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2022-06-07   9.4  10.1  10.5  False   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I could successfully apply this method to my model and it works very well, on top of being very  fast compared to my method. It went from 12 days calculations to 15 hours. A solution without a loop would even be better but I'm already happy with that :) Thank you very much, I've learnt a lot on that one and this is precious to me.
One thing is that when one of the conditions is True on a row when oc is True doesn't seem to be taken it in account. I'm having a deeper look but I don't think it is a big problem in my situation. In any cases, big thanks!

Comment: Actually oc can be True for many rows, which means the conditions are actually delayed to when oc is False again. Any idea on how to prevent that?
Another 'issue' would be that for the line sr['diff'] = oc[sr['r']] - oc['c'] I'm getting the warning 'A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame'.
I've tried using .loc but without success.

Comment: Can you update your post with an example where the condition is True when oc is True please?

Comment: Yeah of course, no worries.
I've managed to reduce the problem by making a copy of oc with shift(1) and a new column based on oc is True and oc_copy is False in order to remove the consecutive oc is True.